# Installing a package with bower

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm, bower

I found a calendar,and i need to install it with bower,but first i had to install node,npm,git.I found node and git on web and i've installed them with wizards.And if i want to use bower i have to install it with:

```
$ npm install -g bower
```

But i get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:44:10)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:117:23)
at bound (domain.js:254:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
```

>

And if i try to install package directly,i've used:

```
$ bower install fullcalendar
```

But it gives me the same error..

I've took those commands from bower and calendar tutorials,but i'm new in those things and i dont really know what's wrong or what i have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows you'll have to install [mysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) with the "Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt" option [as described here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower#windows-users) in the Bower Package description.

Comment: There seems to be something missing. Maybe extract the information from the link and paste it in the question.

Comment: @petersv , alright it worked. I've installed npm and bower with succes.I had to run those cmd lines out of node repl , in win cmd.I also installed that calendar,but i dont know how to acces it, where are the files? or how can i see it  in my localhost? or to put it in a website?

Comment: Installed packages will be placed in a "bower_components" directory which will be created in the folder where the bower program was executed.

Comment: @PetruLebada did my suggestion answer your question?

Comment: @petersv , somehow . This was also one of the problems,but the main issue,was that i had to type it out of the node repl.Anyway your answer was helpful,thanks.